# HTML Code - Something is invalid - Cant Figure Out What

Tags: javascript, html, forms, syntax

I am trying to use an on-completion function for a countdown plugin; however, for whatever reason, dreamweaver is telling me there is a syntax error where I tell it to change the inner HTML of the div contentcontainer.  I have been looking for hours and cant find whats wrong with it.  I was hoping someone could help me out.  Any help is appreciated.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                $('#countdown_dashboard').countDown({
                    targetOffset: {
                        'day':      0,
                        'month':    0,
                        'year':     0,
                        'hour':     0,
                        'min':      5,
                        'sec':      0
                    },
                    onComplete: function() { 
                    document.getElementById('contentcontainer').innerHTML = '<div id="content">
  <div class="success_box">Application Successful!  Redirecting...</div>
    <div class="error_box"></div>
  <div class="formcontainer">
  <form id="formexample" name="example_form" action="#" method="POST">
        <label for="firstname">*First Name:</label>
        <label for="lastname">*Last Name:</label>

      <input name="firstname" id="firstname" />
      <input name="lastname" id="lastname" />

        <label for="username">*Username:</label>
        <label for="email">*Email (A Confirmation Email Will Be Sent Here) :</label>

        <input onKeyPress="makeithappen()" onKeyUp="makeithappen()" name="username" id="username" />
        <input onKeyPress="makeithappenemail()" onKeyUp="makeithappenemail()" name="email" id="email" />

        <label for="password">*Password:</label>
        <label for="password_confirm">*Confirm Password:</label>

        <input onKeyPress="makeithappenemail()" onKeyUp="makeithappenemail()" name="password" id="password" type="password" />
        <input onKeyPress="makeithappen()" onKeyUp="makeithappen()" name="password_confirm" id="password_confirm" type="password" />

    <button class="button gray" type="submit" name="submit">Submit  </button> 
    <input id="usernameused" name="usernameused" type="hidden" value=""> 
    <input id="emailused" name="emailused" type="hidden" value="">
  </form>
  </div>
</div>';
                    }

                });
            });
        </script>
<div id="contentcontainer">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you have a string left open. Javascript does not support multi-line strings with either single (') or double (") quotes.

In other words

```
var d = "hello
world "
```

Is not valid, however, you can use a special character \ to "consume" or "escape" the newline and make it act as if it is a single line string.

```
var d = "hello \
world "
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, let me try and implement this!